# Which code is better according to performance?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a dynamic form where data is added to the database.
I am confused that which way is better to get some data from session outside of loop
or directly i should get the data from session inside my loop.
here is my code 
1- get the data from session and put it in two variables and than called those variable inside the loop.

```
$user_name                  = $this->input->post('user_name');
 $organization_name          = $this->input->post('organization_name');
 $location                   = $this->input->post('location');
 $duration_time              = $this->input->post('duration_time');
 $yearly_expences            = $this->input->post('yearly_expences');
 $expences_source            = $this->input->post('expences_source');
 $remark                     = $this->input->post('remark');

 //-----
 $u_rec_id = $this->session->userdata('rec_id');
 $serial   = $this->session->userdata('serial');
 //-----
 $all_array = array();

 if( $user_name ) {
    if( is_array( $user_name ) ) {

        for( $j = 0 ; $j < count( $user_name ) ; $j++ ) {
           $this ->ci_form = array(
              'user_name'         => $user_name[$j],
              'organization_name' => $organization_name[$j],
              'location'          => $location[$j],
              'duration_time'     => $duration_time[$j],
              'yearly_expences'   => $yearly_expences[$j],
              'expences_source'   => $expences_source[$j],
              'remark'            => $remark[$j],
              'userid'            => $this->m_auth->get_user_id(),
              'u_rec_id'          => $u_rec_id,
              'serial'            => $serial,
              'regdate'           => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')

          );
          array_push( $all_array, $this->ci_form );
      }
   }
```

}

or this way is better
get the data from session directly inside the loop

```
$user_name                  = $this->input->post('user_name');
  $organization_name          = $this->input->post('organization_name');
  $location                   = $this->input->post('location');
  $duration_time              = $this->input->post('duration_time');
  $yearly_expences            = $this->input->post('yearly_expences');
  $expences_source            = $this->input->post('expences_source');
  $remark                     = $this->input->post('remark');


  $all_array = array();

  if( $user_name ) {
     if( is_array( $user_name ) ) {

        for( $j = 0 ; $j < count( $user_name ) ; $j++ ) {
            $this ->ci_form = array(
                'user_name'         => $user_name[$j],
                'organization_name' => $organization_name[$j],
                'location'          => $location[$j],
                'duration_time'     => $duration_time[$j],
                'yearly_expences'   => $yearly_expences[$j],
                'expences_source'   => $expences_source[$j],
                'remark'            => $remark[$j],
                'userid'            => $this->m_auth->get_user_id(),
                'u_rec_id'          => $this->session->userdata('rec_id'),
                'serial'            => $this->session->userdata('serial'),
                'regdate'           => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')
            );
            array_push( $all_array, $this->ci_form );
         }           
       }
    }
```

Comment: it's clear if you avoid the session retrieve process in the loop, it will be faster. But not significant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first approach and save some function calls:

```
$user_name                  = $this->input->post('user_name');
$organization_name          = $this->input->post('organization_name');
$location                   = $this->input->post('location');
$duration_time              = $this->input->post('duration_time');
$yearly_expences            = $this->input->post('yearly_expences');
$expences_source            = $this->input->post('expences_source');
$remark                     = $this->input->post('remark');

$u_rec_id = $this->session->userdata('rec_id');
$serial   = $this->session->userdata('serial');

$all_array = array();

foreach ((array)$user_name as $j=>$each) {
    $this ->ci_form = array(
        'user_name'         => $user_name[$j],
        'organization_name' => $organization_name[$j],
        'location'          => $location[$j],
        'duration_time'     => $duration_time[$j],
        'yearly_expences'   => $yearly_expences[$j],
        'expences_source'   => $expences_source[$j],
        'remark'            => $remark[$j],
        'userid'            => $this->m_auth->get_user_id(),
        'u_rec_id'          => $u_rec_id,
        'serial'            => $serial,
        'regdate'           => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')
    );

    array_push($all_array, $this->ci_form);
}
```